# Testbench can't pass decimal value through wire and reg variables

Tags: verilog

I have two files named: *summation.v* and *summationtest.v*

Code for *summation.v*::

```sv
module summation(a, b, c);
input [3:0] a;
input [3:0] b;
output reg[7:0] c;
reg[3:0] anum;
reg[3:0] bnum;
always @(a) begin
anum <=a;
bnum <=b;
c = anum + bnum;
end
endmodule
```

The purpose of summation.v is to take two decimal input from *summationtest.v*, process the decimal values and send the result `c` back to the output (*summationtest.v*) again.

Code for *summationtest.v*:

```sv
module summationtest;
reg[3:0] a;
reg[3:0] b;
wire[7:0] c;
summation a1(a, b, c);
initial begin
a = 3;
b = 4;
$display("%d", c);
end
endmodule
```

When the program runs, no value of a and b passes from *summationtest.v* to *summation.v*; as a result, no value is assigned to `c`.

Answer (score 0):

That is not the proper way to model combinational logic.  You have an incomplete sensitivity list and you should not use nonblocking assignments (`<=`).  You should use `$monitor` instead of `display` to view all signal changes.

Here is a much simpler way to code your adder:

```
module summation(a, b, c);
    input [3:0] a;
    input [3:0] b;
    output [7:0] c;
    assign c = a + b;
endmodule

module summationtest;
    reg[3:0] a;
    reg[3:0] b;
    wire[7:0] c;
    summation a1(a, b, c);
initial begin
    $monitor("%d", c);
    a = 3;
    b = 4;
end
endmodule
```